# EXC_BAD_ACCESS ( i am changing Orientation )

Tags: iphone

When I put my iPhone on the table while running my application it crashes the second after I pick it up.

Below is the crash log. (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`)

```
objc_msgSend
-[UIWindow _shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:]
-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force]
-[UIWindow _updateInterfaceOrientationFromDeviceOrientation]
-[UIWindow _handleDeviceOrientationChange:]
_nsnote_callback
__CFXNotificationPost
_CFXNotificationPostNotification
-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]
-[UIDevice setOrientation:]
-[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:]
_[UIApplication sendEvent:]
_UIApplicationHandleEvent 
SendEvent
PurpleEventTimerCallBack
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
CFRunLookRunInMode
GSEventRunModel
GSEventRun
-[UIApplication _run]
UIApplicationMain
main
```

Have you any idea what's the problem?

Comment: Some code would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is usually a sign of too early released memory. Check your memory management.

Answer (score 0):

for check how it comes and find where it gets EXC_BAD_ACCESS u must in a DEBUG mode and follow the link

http://iosdevelopertips.com/debugging/tracking-down-exc_bad_access-errors-with-nszombieenabled.html